# Mounting with mount -a fails if present in fstab on booting

Tags: mount, ntfs, fstab

I have mounted an ntfs partition in '/mnt/3TB' in fstab and I am trying to mount a folder from that partition in my home directory. I'm using --bind because my backup software for my home directory prefers it that way.

Mounting in the cli works without a problem, but fstab will mount any directory except for the 'teundrive' directory, the one that I need.

This works perfectly: `sudo mount --bind /mnt/3TB/cloud/teundrive /home/teun/Cloud/drive`

If I try to use fstab and do `sudo mount -a` it fails but without errors. I added this line in fstab.

`/mnt/3TB/cloud/teundrive /home/teun/Cloud/teundrive none rw,user,bind 0 0`

If I create a new directory, e.g. `/mnt/3TB/cloud/testdir` and mount it in fstab the same way, it works perfectly. After trying and failing I created a new directory and moved all the contents of the old one and mounted it with fstab. This also worked.

Yet, after a reboot it does not mount. Changing it to another folder and doing `sudo mount -a` works.

Any idea how I can solve this? I am not too experienced with Ubuntu and with asking these kinds of questions. I hope the problem is clear and I provided enough information. Thanks!